# Optimal Approach for Transmitting and Rendering Large Pixel Art Game Maps in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, procedural-generation, tilemap, content-generation

I'm working on a pixel art game in Unity, and my backend (Which is actually written on Golang) has generated a massive dataset of tiles for a 1000 by 1000 world (it could be even more). I'm wondering about the best approach for transmitting and rendering this map on the Unity client side. Should I consider making a copy of the entire world as an asset for the client, or is it more appropriate to send the map data as JSON or Proto files and parse it in chunks? I'm looking for insights on performance, bandwidth efficiency, and overall best practices for handling large game maps. What strategies have you found effective in similar scenarios, and what considerations should I keep in mind for optimizing the player's experience?

Comment: How many pixels squared is each tile? Is there any repetition of tiles across the world? And do the tiles consist only of pixel data, or game logic data as well? You definitely don't want to use JSON. You would want a compressed binary format for transmission.

Comment: @Engineer
each tile is 1 pixel which contains x and y, in game it is Unit (as my Unity developer says), mostly we generate it for the players, it will have logic like mobs generated there, collision, villages and towns

Comment: @Engineer so it is better to send the data by chunks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest in this case is the following:

- Rendering details like pixel colour, are usually not crucial to game logic. Since you will need to render the 1000x1000 map as a texture, it is best that you send it as a compressed image. PNG for example makes use of RLE compression and is thus lossless (i.e.it loses no detail when being decompressed for display, unlike JPG). Or you can come up with your own compression scheme. 1 byte per pixel indexed colour would be my suggestion, rather than 4 byte RGBA colour. You then have to decide how often this map is allowed to change, and thus how often you have to send out map updates to the various players. These updates to the map colours can be either deltas (efficient) or absolute states (easy to do, but costly to send over network).
- Game data in each chunk (map pixel): you will want to be more selective about, because it could get quite large if it exists for every one of 1000x1000=1M tiles. This is what I call "Area of Interest" around the player(s). You likely don't want to hold gigabytes of data about every single tile (pixel, chunk) on your map, if players are not active in 99% of those tiles. Sure, you could store it all, but the more data you store, the more cache misses you have retrieving that data from main memory, etc. It can often be faster to just *forget* data in cells where players are no longer active, and then *regenerate* that data when you return. Things won't look exactly the same, but in many games this isn't necessary to create an immersive experience. Minecraft for example forgets monsters and how much damage you've done to a block, but it does store deltas showing which blocks were actually added / removed (and of what type). If a lot of terrain editing has been done over time, Minecraft savefiles can become absolutely enormous and 3rd party tools may be used to clean up saved chunks that aren't being used anymore.
- The simplest scheme to set up area of interest around players is a `n x n` sliding window of chunks, where `n==2` or `n==3`. `3x3` is the easiest for beginners. You may also then need to deal with cases where the `n x n` neighbourhood around *different* players overlaps, so as not to process the same chunk twice.

So you have some game design decisions to make before you can proceed.

Comment: Thanks @Engineer !

Comment: @Resorter, just to clarify, you could send the map image (PNG) by HTTP if you're not too hung up on performance or super regular and timely updates. Just makes things that much simpler in the beginning (until you do more serious network optimisations). Also, feel free to accept the answer (checkmark on the left below answer score) if it has  helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I decided to use Tiled program, I will draw map there, then send to client by chunks 100 to 100, using bin file (Tiled program can export JSON, in golang there is also a package to decode .tmx file if needed), Sending 1 mln+ tiles to client from start is a bad Idea, so yes ! You gave me good direction

Comment: I used golang and created map generator using noises for the Generating the core of the map, Land, Forest  and etc, rest I will do in Tiled, because its hard to generate all this stuff (Decorations, Trees, Collision and etc)

Comment: and I will use gRPC for stream of chunks @Engineer